# Open Daylight project build issue

Tags: java, maven, openstack, opendaylight

I have downloaded and imported all the tutorials available in the below git
https://github.com/opendaylight/coretutorials/tree/master/toaster

While doing a maven install i am getting the below issue

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] Downloading: http://nexus.opendaylight.org/content/repositories/opendaylight.snapshot/org/opendaylight/odlparent/odlparent/1.6.0-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
[WARNING] Could not transfer metadata org.opendaylight.odlparent:odlparent:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml from/to opendaylight-snapshot (http://nexus.opendaylight.org/content/repositories/opendaylight.snapshot/): connect timed out
[INFO] Downloading: http://nexus.opendaylight.org/content/repositories/opendaylight.snapshot/org/opendaylight/odlparent/odlparent/1.6.0-SNAPSHOT/odlparent-1.6.0-SNAPSHOT.pom
[ERROR] [ERROR] Some problems were encountered while processing the POMs:
[FATAL] Non-resolvable parent POM for org.opendaylight.toaster:toaster-parent:0.1.0-SNAPSHOT: Could not transfer artifact org.opendaylight.odlparent:odlparent:pom:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT from/to opendaylight-snapshot (http://nexus.opendaylight.org/content/repositories/opendaylight.snapshot/): connect timed out and 'parent.relativePath' points at no local POM @ line 16, column 13
 @ 
[ERROR] The build could not read 1 project -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]   
[ERROR]   The project org.opendaylight.toaster:toaster-parent:0.1.0-SNAPSHOT (C:\Users\609620968\Documents\coretutorials\toaster\ch7-ToasterJMX\parent\pom.xml) has 1 error
[ERROR]     Non-resolvable parent POM for org.opendaylight.toaster:toaster-parent:0.1.0-SNAPSHOT: Could not transfer artifact org.opendaylight.odlparent:odlparent:pom:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT from/to opendaylight-snapshot (http://nexus.opendaylight.org/content/repositories/opendaylight.snapshot/): connect timed out and 'parent.relativePath' points at no local POM @ line 16, column 13 -> [Help 2]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/ProjectBuildingException
[ERROR] [Help 2] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/UnresolvableModelException
```

Am i missing some thing?. it is not able to find the oldparent odlparentlite etc. is there a way to add this into my local maven.

Answer (score 0):

The version specified for the artifact is wrong. Please check [this link](https://nexus.opendaylight.org/content/repositories/opendaylight.snapshot/) and correct the version.